# Occasional crash when accessing NSError.localizedDescription

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nserror

In a Swift 1.2 app, I have some code that logs `NSError` objects. In very rare occasions, I get crash reports from Crashlytics indicating that accessing the `localizedDescription` property caused the crash.

Here's my error logging function:

```
func trackError(error: NSError)
{
    var props = [String: AnyObject]()

    // CRASHES HERE
    props["NSErrorLocalized"] = error.localizedDescription

    props["NSErrorCode"] = error.code
    props["NSErrorDomain"] = error.domain

    if let userInfo = error.userInfo {
        props["NSErrorUserInfo"] = userInfo
    }

    self.trackEvent("Error", withProperties: props)
}
```

And here's the call stack reported by Crashlytics:

```
0 CoreFoundation  CFHash + 129
1 CoreFoundation  CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1204
2 CoreFoundation  CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1204
3 CoreFoundation  CFDictionaryGetValue + 106
4 CoreFoundation  _CFErrorCreateLocalizedDescription + 266
5 Foundation      -[NSError localizedDescription] + 82
```

I was thinking on directly accessing the `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` in `error.userInfo` instead of via the `localizedDescription` property, but since the callstack implies that it crashes while accessing a dictionary (which is most probably the `userInfo` dict), I am afraid that it would not fix anything.

I don't mind not including the `localizedDescription` in my error log if there is none, but I need a safe way to check if there is one or not without crashing...

Something that might be noteworthy: it seems like the `NSError` objects that cause this crash are ones that are returned by the Parse SDK. I have no way to be sure of this, but there are some clues in the rest of my logs that seem to imply this.

I have tried to reproduce this by forcing error situations with various calls to the Parse SDK, but my error logging code handle them without any problems and the `localizedDescription` property returns a valid string without crashing.

Anybody else has seen this and has any clue on what is going on?

Comment: did you figure out the reason for the crash while accessing the localizedDescription ?

Comment: I ended up working around it by doing `if let localizedDescription = error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] as? String {}` instead of accessing the property directly.

Comment: @PascalBourque you should update your post with this answer, it's the solution and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up working around it by doing:

```
if let localizedDescription = error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] as? String {}
```

instead of accessing the property directly.

Answer (score 8):

One possible way this could crash is if errors are created (in Objective-C) like `[NSError new]` or `[[NSError alloc] init]` (i.e., not calling the designated initializer).  At least in iOS9, that returns a valid instance, but its internals are not properly initialized and can crash if you call methods on it.  Calling -userInfo just returns an empty dictionary, but trying to access other internal state like -localizedDescription and similar methods can do will cause crashes.

Comment: This seems like a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

Call from the view

```
func addBorderCircle() {
    let radius : CGFloat = bounds.width / 2
    let reoundedRect = CGRect(x: .zero, y: .zero, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:  reoundedRect, cornerRadius: .zero)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: .zero, endAngle: Double.pi*2, clockwise: true)
    
    path.append(circlePath)
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
    
    let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
    fillLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    fillLayer.opacity = 0.4
    layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
guard let descriptionKey = self.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] as? String else { return false }
/// use descriptionKey here
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you check if `localizedDescription` property is not set to nil? Try something like this...

```
if let errorLocalizedDescription = localizedDescription as! String {
    props["NSErrorLocalized"] = error.localizedDescription
}
```

Comment: The property is declared as a non-optional String, so I can't do that.